# How do i run an executeable with FFI in lua

Tags: windows, winapi, lua, ffi

Since im not able to use `os.execute()` in my current project but im able to use everything from LuaJIT's FFI and i dont understand c/c++ i would like to know how to execute and .exe file with ffi

Comment: FFI is used for accessing methods of binary C libraries like .dll files and a.files. It may be possible to create/find a library that opens a external program

Comment: but in other note... maybe io.popen could be a solution

Comment: i cant use io.open either.

Answer (score 0):

```
local ffi = require("ffi")

ffi.cdef[[
typedef struct _STARTUPINFOA {
  uint32_t  cb;
  void *    lpReserved;
  void *    lpDesktop;
  void *    lpTitle;
  uint32_t  dwX;
  uint32_t  dwY;
  uint32_t  dwXSize;
  uint32_t  dwYSize;
  uint32_t  dwXCountChars;
  uint32_t  dwYCountChars;
  uint32_t  dwFillAttribute;
  uint32_t  dwFlags;
  uint16_t  wShowWindow;
  uint16_t  cbReserved2;
  void *    lpReserved2;
  void **   hStdInput;
  void **   hStdOutput;
  void **   hStdError;
} STARTUPINFOA, *LPSTARTUPINFOA;
typedef struct _PROCESS_INFORMATION {
  void **  hProcess;
  void **  hThread;
  uint32_t dwProcessId;
  uint32_t dwThreadId;
} PROCESS_INFORMATION, *LPPROCESS_INFORMATION;
uint32_t CreateProcessA(
  void *,
  const char * commandLine,
  void *,
  void *,
  uint32_t,
  uint32_t,
  void *,
  const char * currentDirectory,
  LPSTARTUPINFOA,
  LPPROCESS_INFORMATION
);
uint32_t CloseHandle(void **);
]]

local function execute(commandLine, currentDirectory)
   local si = ffi.new"STARTUPINFOA"
   si.cb = ffi.sizeof(si)
   local pi = ffi.new"PROCESS_INFORMATION"
   local ok = ffi.C.CreateProcessA(nil, commandLine, nil, nil, 0, 0, nil, currentDirectory, si, pi) ~= 0
   if ok then
      ffi.C.CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)
      ffi.C.CloseHandle(pi.hThread)
   end
   return ok  -- true/false
end

execute[["C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe" "some file.txt"]]

if not execute[["C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Minesweeper\MineSweeper.exe"]] then
   print"Can not find the game"
end
```

Comment: While using thi im getting following error and im not able to fix it by myself: missing declaration for symbol 'CreateProcessA'

Comment: This probably means you're NOT able `to use everything from LuaJIT's FFI`  In other words, your LuaJIT FFI is sandboxed, and WinAPI is not accessible.

Comment: You can try to load library `local lib = ffi.load"kernel32"` and use `lib.*` everywhere instead of `ffi.C.*`

Comment: Or maybe `ffi.cdef` is deliberately replaced with a stub to disable invoking external functions.